# javascript setAttribute function

Tags: javascript, wait, setattribute

I have a problem with the `setAttribute` function.

Here my code

```
mind.SetRequest(rec_input.value);
mind.Reply();
element.setAttribute('text', mind.GetReply());
element.speak();
```

`element.speak()` isn't waiting for `setAttribute` to be completed.

Is there any function to call `speak()` when `setAttribute` is finished?

The `img.onload = function(){ . . . }` function called after the `img` is loaded, is there a similar way where I can call my `speak` function after `setAttribute`?

Comment: `setAttribute()` is synchronous. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: provide a test page with jsBin.

Comment: @MattBall `element.speak();` makes me think that `element` is not DOM element. However who knows, maybe OP extended it with custom methods..

Comment: It's possible that `mind.GetReply()` is async. We definitely need a lot more code from OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
mind.SetRequest(rec_input.value);
mind.Reply();
element.setAttribute('text', mind.GetReply());
setTimeout(function () {
   element.speak();
}, 0);
```

`setAttribute()` is synchronous, but it is DOM-based method. It means browser needs some additional processor ticks to set that attribute. So use timeouts to move code execution (that tries to get that attribute) to the next event loop.

Comment: Hi Max , I am trying your method, but in this way speak function didnt called

Comment: can you tell me more, why in this way all goes well, but my method didnt worked, 
or where I can read about it more , thank you

Comment: @Gor Yes, sure.

In short: setTimeout(element.speak, 0) didn't work because of .speak() is DOM API provided by `SpeechSynthesis` class and DOM APIs can't be called in that way, because setTimeout call `fn.apply(this, ...)` and it looses the context. But if you wrap `element.speak()` into anonymous function is saves context (`this` is linked with `element`).

But that is not all. Since you set `text` attribute (DOM operation) you need move all code requires this attribute to the next loop of life cycle. It's called multi-tasking. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/1453833